# SQL row is only varchar(10) but has 30+ characters in it

Tags: sql, sql-server, truncate, varchar

table on external database (when I click modify) states that row A is a varchar(10) but when I look at the data there is obviously many more characters in it. How is this possible?

This concerns me because when I pull data from that row, I only get 10 characters, and the rest is cut off.  I am not allowed to modify the external database tables.

Comment: Microsoft SQL   Transact

Answer (score 2):

*How is this possible?*
The column was probably originally a varchar(30) and was subsequently altered to varchar(10).  I assume data has been written since the change to varchar(10), which makes this a true mess.  If altering the column back to a length of 30 is not possible, I would investigate the implications of truncating the old data to 10 characters.

*Update*
run the following statement to confirm the column length:

```
select character_maximum_length
from information_schema.columns
where table_name='tablename' and COLUMN_NAME='columnname'
```

Update 2:

```
select max(len(column_name))
from tablename
```

Comment: No the newest data also exceeds 30+40 characters even though there is a varchar(10) limit..They have a frontend entering the data in and a boat load of procedures, cascading update/insert/del triggers so could this allow them to override varchar(10) limit?

Comment: User589983: I just ran your code, and it says Character_maximum_length: 10

Comment: I get 10 again. I also did a select and compared the length of each item in that row. I think when I select it  10 is max, but when I open up the table on the remote server and look at the raw data (without selecting) I see 30+ characters.

Comment: How do you look at the raw data without selecting?

Comment: Giving you a +1 since I don't think OP knows what he is talking about.

Comment: User589983: I select it by: select rowa from remoteserver.database.dbo.table1   The selected data is always less then 10 characters. However when I log into the remote server with my sql credentials and view the table data there is more then 10 characters. Makes no sense since its a varchar(10) It should be 10 characters no matter how I view/select it. We have customers complaining about truncated data when its clearly all here, just its over the varchar(10) limit, therefore when I select it, I only get the first 10 characters. AND JNK I know what I am talking about. I flagged you.